# Is there a way to install the Mobile Emulation tools in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, emulation, emulator, google-chrome-canary

Google removed the emulation tools from Chrome, and it's now achievable in [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html), which I don't want to install.

Is there a way to get it in the regular installation of Chrome I have on my computer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mobile emulation is still available in the current version of chrom (as of 6 May 14, that would be version 34.0.1847.131). Hit F12, open the "drawer":

[image: Chrome console drawer icon]

Then on the bottom tab, pick "emulation" and the device from the dropdown:

[image: Chrome sample emulate session]

Answer (score 2):

It is still available on your Chrome and is not removed from the Google Chrome, you can go to the following link to understand more about it.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

As the above page describes that these tools are still present in regular Google Chrome. But the only thing is that, Regular Chrome isn't meant for Developers. It is for general usage, that's why the DevTools won't be as much powerfull as they might be on the Chrome Canary.

Here is the reason for that: (A qoute from the site)

> **Note:** Some of our documentation may be ahead of the stable version of Chrome. If you are unable to locate a feature listed, we recommend trying Chrome Canary which contains the latest version of the DevTools.

Now I think you would understand that these tools are meant for Developers since general public won't need them. So they don't bother adding these features to the browser for public.

They create a seperate Browser meant for Developers and provide these tools in that.

Comment: I understand that, but why a separate browser. An extension would make much more sense. I don't won't to install no other browsers.

Comment: But I think that's what they want. I don't have a choice on that neither do you. :(

Comment: See jdh's [answer](http://superuser.com/a/750423/9825).